# JS - Object Constructor Methods

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I am trying to make an object that includes the teams points (as shown below where it says "this.update"). When I run the program it does not seem to give the points to the teams and it does not seem to even evaluate both teams' goals.

I want the team1Points and team2Points properties to be derived from an IF statement like the one above or another solution would help, akin to the 1 point to both teams for a draw, 3 points for a win, 0 for a loss.

```js
teamsArray = ["Blue Team", "Red Team"];

function match(team1Name, team2Name, team1Goals, team2Goals) {
  this.team1Name = team1Name;
  this.team1Goals = team1Goals;
  this.team2Name = team2Name;
  this.team2Goals = team2Goals;
  this.update = function() {
    if (team1Goals > team2Goals) {
      team1Points = 3;
      team2Points = 0;
    } else if (team2Goals > team1Goals) {
      team2Points = 3;
      team1Points = 0;
    } else if (team1Goals == team2Goals) {
      team1Points = 1;
      team2Points = 1;
    }
  };
  this.update();
}

testMatch();

function testMatch() {
  var match1 = new match(teamsArray[0], teamsArray[1], 2, 0);
  console.log(match1);
}
```

Comment: Try `this.team1Points = 0` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method creates global variables instead of properties, and you never even called it!

In order to avoid issues like this, I suggest switching to the modern JavaScript syntax. Begin your scripts with the instruction `'use strict';` to enable strict mode and define variables using `let` instead of `var`. If you do that, the browser won't let you define global variables from within a function.

As for the solution to your code:

```
function match(team1Name, team2Name, team1Goals, team2Goals) {
  this.team1Name = team1Name;
  this.team1Goals = team1Goals;
  this.team2Name = team2Name;
  this.team2Goals = team2Goals;
  this.team1Points = this.team2Points = 0;

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.team1Goals > this.team2Goals) {
      this.team1Points = 3;
      this.team2Points = 0;
    } else if (this.team2Goals > this.team1Goals) {
      this.team2Points = 3;
      this.team1Points = 0;
    } else if (this.team1Goals == this.team2Goals) {
      this.team1Points = 1;
      this.team2Points = 1;
    }
  };
}
```

And don't forget to call `.update()` somewhere.

```
m = new match("Alpha", "Beta", 0, 2);
m.update();

console.log("Team " + m.team1Name + " has " + m.team1Points + " points.");
console.log("Team " + m.team2Name + " has " + m.team2Points + " points.");
```

Comment: Wow, sorry if you noticed that horrible sequence of edits. I'm a bit rusty on SO usage.

Comment: I forgot to add in the team1Points and team2Points variables but it doesnt really answer my question.

I tried to do console.log(testMatch.update()) and it doesnt really solve the question.

I am trying to get team1Points to = 3 as they have scored more goals. Maybe I am calling the update() function wrong im unsure

Comment: The update function doesn't return anything, so logging its result won't do. You'll want to log the variables themselves if you want to check their values.

Comment: How do i do that? I am quite confused about this

Comment: @Jay I edited the answer with an example of how you'd create a match and log the results.

Comment: It looks good. But when I try to update the score by doing

m.team1Goals += 3; (to make the score 3 - 2)

and then call m.update();

the result is still 3 points to the beta team when the points should read

alpha: 3
beta: 0 (as the beta team are currently losing)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I forgot to add `this.` in the conditions as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
teamsArray = ["Blue Team", "Red Team"];

function match(team1Name, team2Name, team1Goals, team2Goals) {
  this.team1Name = team1Name;
  this.team1Goals = team1Goals;
  this.team2Name = team2Name;
  this.team2Goals = team2Goals;
  this.update = function() {
    if (team1Goals > team2Goals) {
      this.team1Points = 3;
      this.team2Points = 0;
    } else if (team2Goals > team1Goals) {
      this.team2Points = 3;
      this.team1Points = 0;
    } else if (team1Goals == team2Goals) {
      this.team1Points = 1;
      this.team2Points = 1;
    }
  };
  this.update();
}

testMatch();

function testMatch() {
  var match1 = new match(teamsArray[0], teamsArray[1], 2, 0);
  console.log(match1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
teamsArray = ["Blue Team", "Red Team"];

function match(team1Name, team2Name, team1Goals, team2Goals) {
  this.team1Name = team1Name;
  this.team1Goals = team1Goals;
  this.team2Name = team2Name;
  this.team2Goals = team2Goals;
  this.update = function() {
    if (team1Goals > team2Goals) {
      team1Points = 3;
      team2Points = 0;
      return "team1 win"
    } else if (team2Goals > team1Goals) {
      team2Points = 3;
      team1Points = 0;
      return "team2 win"
    } else if (team1Goals == team2Goals) {
      team1Points = 1;
      team2Points = 1;
      return "draw"
    }
  };
}

testMatch();

function testMatch() {
  var match1 = new match(teamsArray[0], teamsArray[1], 2, 0);

  console.log(match1.update());
}
```